# C++ function dispatch with template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, dispatch

I'm in the process of refactoring a large class -- let's call it `Big` -- that has a huge amount of copy-paste code. Much of this copy-paste code exists in `switch` `case`s where only the types involved end up being different. The code is switching based on an `enum` member variable of the class whose value is known only at runtime.

My attempt to fix this involves having a `Dispatcher` class that looks up appropriately typed functions via a `static` function called `lookup()`. The functions that do the actual work are always called `go()` and have to be defined in a wrapper class template (whose sole parameter is the runtime `enum` value currently being switched on). The `go()` functions may or may not be template functions themselves.

Here is a distilled version of the code. My apologies for the length, but this was as short as I could get it without losing important context.

```
#include <cassert>

class Big
{
    public:

        enum RuntimeValue { a, b };

        Big(RuntimeValue rv) : _rv(rv) { }

        bool equals(int i1, int i2)
        {
            return Dispatcher<Equals, bool(int, int)>::lookup(_rv)(i1, i2);
        }

        template<typename T>
        bool isConvertibleTo(int i)
        {
            return Dispatcher<IsConvertibleTo, bool(int)>::lookup<T>(_rv)(i);
        }

    private:

        template<RuntimeValue RV>
        struct Equals
        {
            static bool go(int i1, int i2)
            {
                // Pretend that this is some complicated code that relies on RV
                // being a compile-time constant.
                return i1 == i2;
            }
        };

        template<RuntimeValue RV>
        struct IsConvertibleTo
        {
            template<typename T>
            static bool go(int i)
            {
                // Pretend that this is some complicated code that relies on RV
                // being a compile-time constant.
                return static_cast<T>(i) == i;
            }
        };

        template<template<RuntimeValue> class FunctionWrapper, typename Function>
        struct Dispatcher
        {
            static Function * lookup(RuntimeValue rv)
            {
                switch (rv)
                {
                    case a: return &FunctionWrapper<a>::go;
                    case b: return &FunctionWrapper<b>::go;

                    default: assert(false); return 0;
                }
            }

            template<typename T>
            static Function * lookup(RuntimeValue rv)
            {
                switch (rv)
                {
                    case a: return &FunctionWrapper<a>::go<T>;
                    case b: return &FunctionWrapper<b>::go<T>;

                    default: assert(false); return 0;
                }
            }

            // And so on as needed...
            template<typename T1, typename T2>
            static Function * lookup(RuntimeValue rv);
        };

        RuntimeValue _rv;
};

int main()
{
    Big big(Big::a);

    assert(big.equals(3, 3));
    assert(big.isConvertibleTo<char>(123));
}
```

This mostly works, except that:

1. It builds and works fine under Visual C++ 9 (2008), but under GCC 4.8 it results in compilation errors in the function-template overload of `lookup()`.
2. It requires that a new function-template overload of `lookup()` be written for every new number of function template parameters that we want to support in `go()`.
3. It's cumbersome and confusing to use.

Here are the errors that occur under GCC:

```
Big.cpp: In static member function 'static Function* Big::Dispatcher<FunctionWrapper, Function>::lookup(Big::RuntimeValue)':
Big.cpp(66,65) : error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
                         case a: return &FunctionWrapper<a>::go<T>;
                                                                 ^
Big.cpp(66,66) : error: expected primary-expression before ';' token
                         case a: return &FunctionWrapper<a>::go<T>;
                                                                  ^
Big.cpp(67,65) : error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
                         case b: return &FunctionWrapper<b>::go<T>;
                                                                 ^
Big.cpp(67,66) : error: expected primary-expression before ';' token
                         case b: return &FunctionWrapper<b>::go<T>;
                                                                  ^
```

My question is twofold:

1. Why is this failing to build under GCC, and how do I fix it?
2. Is there a better (i.e., less cumbersome and confusing) way to do this?

The code has to be compilable under Visual C++ 9 (2008), so I can't use anything C++11-specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `go` is a dependent name of a template, you need to use the `template` disambiguator:

```
case a: return &FunctionWrapper<a>::template go<T>;
//                                  ^^^^^^^^
case b: return &FunctionWrapper<b>::template go<T>;
//                                  ^^^^^^^^
```

This tells the compiler to parse what follows the scope resolution operator (`::`) as the name of a template, and the subsequent angular brackets as delimiters for the template arguments.

> Why is this failing to build under GCC, and how do I fix it?

Because GCC is conforming to the Standard, and performs [two-phase name lookup](http://blog.llvm.org/2009/12/dreaded-two-phase-name-lookup.html), while MSVC delays name lookup until instantiation time and, therefore, knows that `go` is the name of a template.

Before instantiation this information is not available, because it is impossible to know what `T` is, and the primary template could be specialized for a given `T` so that `go` is not the name of a member function template, but rather of a data member.

This said, I expect MSVC to support the `template` disambiguator anyway, so adding it should make your program compile both on GCC/Clang/whatever-conforms-to-the-Standard and on MSVC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any advice regarding the second part of my question? Although this scheme works (thanks to your help), I'm not really happy with it. I explored using virtual functions as an alternative, but I hit a brick wall when I realized that this would require virtual function templates, which C++ does not support.

Comment: @Spire: I must confess I did not take the time to analyse the design and what your program actually does, I just spotted those two mistakes and thought I'd post an answer. Unfortunately I do not have time right now to study it (I have ugly bugs to kill in my programs too ;))

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a command dispatcher:

```
#include <map>

// because std::invoke is not in this compiler version.
#define CALL_MEMBER_FN(object,ptrToMember) ((object).*(ptrToMember))

template <class MyType, class cmd_type, class ret_type, typename... Args>
class CommandDispatcher {
    typedef ret_type (MyType::*CommandFunction)(Args... args);
public:
    // create using static/existing map
    CommandDispatcher(std::map<cmd_type, CommandFunction>& cmd_map) : _command_table(cmd_map) {}

    ret_type operator()(MyType& my_obj, cmd_type cmd, Args... args) 
    {
        int retval = 0;

        if (_command_table.find(cmd) == _command_table.end()) {
            std::cerr << "No command implementation found: " << cmd << endl;
            return -EINVAL;
        }
        return CALL_MEMBER_FN(my_obj, _command_table[cmd])(args...);
    }
private:
    std::map<cmd_type, CommandFunction>& _command_table;
};
```

Using it looks like:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() : _dispatcher(_command_map) {}
private:
    static std::map<int,  CommandFunction> _command_map;
    CommandDispatcher<MyClass, int, int, const char*, int> _dispatcher;
};
```

And in cpp:

```
std::map<int, CommandFunction> MyClass::_command_map{
    {E_CMD1, &MyClass::Cmd1},
    {E_CMD2, &MyClass::Cmd2},
};
```